# Vuforia device and cloud use together

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I want to use vuforia cloud and device database together but i can't. Screen display available(2 cube objects overlap) please help me?
How can I device and cloud database together?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHF8p.png)

Comment: There should be no problem using them both together from my experience - what is your exact problem? and how does the image relate to the problem?

Comment: 2 cube object overlap on 1 image target but it must be 1 cube on 1 image @yakobom